# In VB6 using a connection object OpenRecordset how do I open a sproc?

Tags: vb6, asp-classic

I'm trying to open a sproc in vb6, I can successfully open a sproc fine in asp, but vb6 it is having problems opening up the stored procedure.  Here is the code I'm trying:

```
     qryStr = "DECLARE  @return_value int EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[spSproc]"
```

it has no return parameters ... just a select * from orders in the sproc and it runs fine in sql.

```
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = new ADODB.Recordset
rs = co.OpenRecordset(qryStr, dbOptimistic)
```

I don't have problems with opening up queries, but opening up sprocs seems to be the problem.  This should be a read only and I'm not passing any parameters.  thx

Comment: What type of object is `co`?  `OpenRecordset` and `dbOptimistic` are DAO constants, but `rs` is declared as an ADO Recordset.

Comment: Use an ADO Command object: set its CommandText property equal to the proc name, Add to its Parameters collection, and call its Execute method which will return a Recordset object.

Comment: Its a connection object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, there are two recordset objects in VB6.  One is

```
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
```

and the other is

```
Dim rs as Recordset
```

The second one which does not include the ADODB behaves like the Recordset in ASP.  That way I can use my rs.open qryStr, connectionObject

Answer (score 1):

Probably all you need to do is set the commandtype, but you might want to check out this article anyway: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/simple_sp_vb6.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't have access to VB6 to check this properly, but i think you just need to remove the 'Declare @return_value ' from your SQL string, so it reads:

```
qryStr = "EXEC spSproc"
```

Hope this does the trick for you.